# HQL generic mapped class

Tags: nhibernate, hql

Have this C# FNH config:

```
public class MapTag : ClassMap<Tag<Expense>>
```

Both Tag and Expense has a parameterless constructor.

How do I write an HQL that gets all Tag?

_"from Tag<Expense>" don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's supported.

All the other APIs work (Criteria, QueryOver, Linq and SQL).

As a workaround, you can also create a class, `ExpenseTag : Tag<Expense>` and use that instead.